# Word to indicate the naming process of something due to an oft repeated name not originally pertaining to it

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, syntactic-analysis

A word that describes the naming process of something, because it was so much repeated, like a nick name.

Presently, The Company,(city) _______(Named thus by a general saying of a name) was a show of lights, very different from its former self.

Comment: Perhaps [genericization](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/genericization)?

Comment: I believe you hit the spot! "The Company, named thus by a wide generization, was a show of lights, very different from its former self."

Comment: Maybe [metonymy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/metonym)? This is when a name is used for a closely associated concept, such as using "The White House" to refer to the presidential administration.

Comment: Interesting... but would it apply to the casual act of nicknaming? Say, a person is named John, but he is missing one foot, so it's become popular to call him "One Foot", now everybody knows him by that name.

Comment: But seeing some examples of it I think this could work... Since in my context it is a city named differently but refers to the same thing. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding your example very well, but I suspect the word you are looking for here is **eponym**.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym):

> An eponym is a person, place, or thing for whom or for which something is named, or believed to be named. For example, *Elizabeth I of England* is the eponym of the *Elizabethan* era. Many genericized trademarks such as *aspirin*, *heroin* and *thermos* are based on their original brand eponyms.

So, accordingly:

> The Company, **eponymously** named, was a show of lights, very different
>   from its former self.

Comment: Very interesting word, eponym (n.) "one whose name becomes that of a place, a people, an era, an institution, etc., 1833, from Greek eponymos "given as a name, giving one's name to something," as a plural noun (short for eponymoi heroes) denoting founders (legendary or real) of tribes, cities, etc.; from comb. form of epi "upon, (called) after," (see epi-) + onyma, Aeolic dialectal variant of onoma "name" (see name (n.)). According to the etymology of the word Onoma "Name," I wonder if in the sentence it would be redundant to say "Eponymously named," What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: it would work considering that the city's name has become that of an influential structure, "Eleusis, a town becoming the name of the hero Eleusis," "The Company, becoming the name of a small shop that influence the rise of a civilization."

Comment: I don't think it's redundant. While the root might mean *name*, the word itself does not. the ODO has 2 examples which use *eponymously titled*, which is pretty damn close to *eponymously named* in my book. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eponymous?q=eponymously#eponymous__5

Comment: Would you dare give further explanation in the sentence, such as something like this, "The Company, eponymously named after the shop that gave rise to it."?

Comment: I probably would, if it was not clear otherwise.